# Catching UnknownHostException in JDBC class

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, exception, c3p0

I'm using JDBC and c3p0 for connecting a Swing application to a PostgreSQL database. When connection is dead, it uncontrollably raises several PSQLException and UnknownHostException, which is expected.

```
ago 17, 2017 5:39:25 PM org.postgresql.Driver connect
GRAVE: Connection error: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: El intento de conexión falló.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:275)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: academico.ulasalle.edu.pe
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:68)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144)
    ... 13 more
```

I want to catch those UnknownHostExceptions at once so they won't mess the usability of the application.

Where and how should I catch those UnknownHostException? I've tried all around but nothing worked.

This is my BDConnection class:

```
public class BDConnection {
    private String m_cc;
    private String m_Driver;
    public Statement statement;
    public Connection conn;     
    ComboPooledDataSource m_Conexion;

    public BDConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        m_Driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
        m_cc = "jdbc:postgresql://myserver.com/mydb";
        open();
    }

    public ComboPooledDataSource GetConexion() {
        return m_Conexion;
    }

    public void open() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        try {
            if (m_Conexion == null) {
                m_Conexion = new ComboPooledDataSource();
                m_Conexion.setDriverClass( m_Driver ); 
                m_Conexion.setJdbcUrl( m_cc );
                m_Conexion.setUser("user"); 
                m_Conexion.setPassword("password");     
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public boolean isOpen() throws SQLException {
        return (m_Conexion != null);
    }

    public void close() throws SQLException {
        if (isOpen()) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }

    public ResultSet RS_Query(String SQL){
        try {
            conn = m_Conexion.getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(SQL); 
            conn.commit();
            return result;
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            m_Conexion.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void RS_Update(String SQL){
        try {
            conn = m_Conexion.getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate(SQL);
            conn.commit();
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            m_Conexion.close();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, before taking a look at the specific problem, there are a bunch of problems with this class. it looks like you close() the Connection pool after each query, which is not great. a Connection pool should be long-lived; only the Connection should be closed at the end of the query. it's the Connection, not the Connection pool, that should be closed in your finally block (or better yet, use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) with the Connection as the resource.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm changing that.

Answer (score 1):

A clarification right away: the `UnknownHostException` is not thrown directly, but it is wrapped (possibly, indirectly) in some `SQLException`.

I suppose you get that wrapping exception caught by

```
} catch (final SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
```

in your `RS_Query()` method.

One strategy would be to catch the exception wrapping `UnknownHostException` there, wrap it in your custom runtime exception and allow it fly to the UI where you would be able to catch it and display an error window (or a non-blocking pop-up)

```
} catch (final SQLException e) {
    if (causedByUnknownHostException(e)) {
        throw new RuntimeUnknownHostException(e);
    } else {
        // processing somehow an exception which is not caused by UnknownHostException
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} finally {
```

where `RuntimeUnknownHostException` extends `RuntimeException`.

And then handle it in your global UI exception handler:

```
try {
    // some code calling conn.RS_Query(...);
} catch (RuntimeUnknownHostException e) {
    ... display the error message
}
```

Detection code:

```
private boolean causedByUnknownHostException(Throwable t) {
    if (t == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (t instanceof UnknownHostException) {
        return true;
    }
    return causedByUnknownHostException(t.getCause());
}
```

Why make the exception unchecked (extends `RuntimeException`)? This would allow to avoid the burden of declaring it in all your intermediary methods, so it could reach your centralized UI exception handler.

Comment: I tried it but the exception is not caught there. Also, when I attempt to catch UnknownHostException there, that block is indicated as unreachable since the exception is never thrown from inside the 'try' block.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, of course `UnknownHostException` does not extend `SQLException`, but in your case it is wrapped by a subclass of `SQLException`. Updated the answer according to this.